# printing a linux variable with php shell access

Tags: php, linux, centos, phpseclib

I'm trying to `echo` a variable which is defined in Linux (Centos 6.3).
For accessing the server I use `phpseclib 2.0`.

When accessing using PuTTY (or similar), with `vfrepc86` user, i'm getting the following output:

```
vfrepc86@illin935!:vfrepc86> echo $USER
vfrepc86
vfrepc86@illin935!:vfrepc86> pwd
/vfuser1/vfr/abp/vfrepc86
vfrepc86@illin935!:vfrepc86> echo $WL_HOME
/opt/weblogic1211_new/wlserver_12.1
```

When I try running the same with PHP (connecting with the same user `vfrepc86`), using the following code:

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('illin935');
if (!$ssh->login('vfrepc86', '******')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo "---User:---";
echo "<br>";
    echo $ssh->exec('echo $USER');
echo "<br><br>";
echo "---Location of run:---";
echo "<br>";
    echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo "<br><br>";
echo "---Default:---";
echo "<br>";
    echo $ssh->exec('echo $WL_HOME'); //my first try, returns nothing
echo "<br><br>";
echo "---Using su:---";
echo "<br>";
    echo $ssh->exec('su - vfrepc86 -c \'echo $PATH\''); //tried with su
echo "<br><br>";
echo "---Writing to file:---";
echo "<br>";
    echo $ssh->exec('echo $WL_HOME >> temp.txt'); //tried writing to file

?>
```

I get the following:

```
---User:---
vfrepc86

---Location of run:---
/vfuser1/vfr/abp/vfrepc86 

---Default:---


---Using su:---
standard in must be a tty 

---Writing to file:---
```

You can see I'm not able to get the `$WL_HOME`. Though the script is running from the same path. As seen above, I've also tried using `su` but that returns `standard in must be a tty`. Printing the command to a file doesnt help, as the file gets empty.

Comment: Well, down voting is fine, but at least a comment why was this down voted almost a year after it was written. I think it is well written and formatted question. A comment from the down-voter is expected... unless the down vote is pointless for me and other users for future learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NET_SSH2` does not request an interactive shell, so your `.profile` doesn't get executed. That's why `$WM_HOME` is not defined.

Instead of `phpseclib`, use the PECL `ssh2` extension, it has a function [`ssh2_shell`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-shell.php) that requests an interactive shell.

Comment: Where is that variable set? `NET_SSH2` doesn't create an interactive login shell, so your profile script isn't run.

Comment: In `.profile`: `export WL_HOME=/opt/weblogic1211_new/wlserver_12.1`

Comment: `.profile` is only executed for interactive login shells. SSH2 isn't creating a login shell.

Comment: I see, do you have any recommendation for extension that does it ?

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime i've used `echo $ssh->exec('grep \'export WL_HOME=\' .profile');` as a temporary solution.

Comment: @Barmar - your answer is sufficiently misleading such that I'd classify it as being flat out wrong. phpseclib does not, by default, request an interactive shell, but it can be made to do so as elaborated in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36240665/569976

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions.

1. Enable a PTY (`$ssh->enablePTY()`) and then do `$ssh->exec('command')`. More info: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html
2. Use an interactive shell. eg. `$ssh->read('[prompt]'); $ssh->write("command\n"); echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');`. More info: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive